# Understanding DSL Query Properties

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

The ElasticSearch DSL query language contains a number of different search operations and I'm trying to understand the property naming conventions of the different clauses.

Specifically [Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and [Fuzzy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) do fundamentally similar things, searching for text with different restrictions on what is considered a hit. There are two fairly straight forward examples below.

What I'm struggling to understand is the variation in the name of the properties containing the search text. For a Match query the search text goes into a query property, while for a fuzzy query the property is called value.

Additionally the term "query" has a broader meaning as rankable searching functions distinct from "filters" that doesn't seem to fit with the use for the Match query property name.

Is there a distinction between Match "query" and Fuzzy "value" that explains the different terms?
Is there some connection between Match "query" and generic top level "query" that I'm missing?

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "this is a test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "user.id": {
        "value": "ki"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a distinction between Match "query" and Fuzzy "value" that explains the different terms?

Yes, ther is a distinction. A `match query` accepts a full text which is analyzed before matching whereas the `fuzzy value` searches for a single term.

Elasticsearch itself distinguishes between [Full text queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) (e.g. match) and [Term-level queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html) (e.g. fuzzy).

From the documentation:

> Unlike full-text queries, term-level queries do not analyze search terms. Instead, term-level queries match the exact terms stored in a field.

So as we're concentrating on a single term in the fuzzy query, it makes sense for me to use another terminology here.